# BigEndian or LittleEndian read

Tags: c++, byte

Я пытаюсь сконвертировать массив из восьми «байт» в `unsigned _int64`, но получаю

```
C8BA94B1
```

вместо нужного

```
B194BAC8
```

Я не знаю, как это исправить.

Мой код:

```
std::array<unsigned __uint64, 8> S;
S = { 177,148,186,200,10,8,245,59 };
unsigned __int64 byteS = (S.at(0)     |
        (S.at(1) << 8  |
        (S.at(2) << 16 |
        (S.at(3) << 24 |
        (S.at(4) << 32 |
        (S.at(5) << 40 |
        (S.at(6) << 48 |
        (S.at(7) << 56;

printf("%X", byteS[0]);
```

Я пыталась изменить направление 0..7, 7..0, но это не помогло. Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: Оно у вас вообще компилируется?... :( И - задайте свой вопрос по-русски, все ж таки тут RU SO :)

Comment: Исправила:) Проблема в конвертации : у меня считывается как BigEndian, а мне необходимо LittleEndian

Comment: Это код вообще не компилируем. О каком  BigEndian/LittleEndian может идти речь? Что такое `byteS[i]`? При чем здесь какое-то `i` и почему это вообще массив?

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, надо бы комментарием, но ни места, ни форматирования...
Распишем подробнее:

```
int main()
{
    array<unsigned __int64, 8> S;
    S = { 177,148,186,200,10,8,245,59 };
    unsigned __int64 byteS = (S.at(0))     |
        (S.at(1) << 8)  |
        (S.at(2) << 16) |
        (S.at(3) << 24) |
        (S.at(4) << 32) |
        (S.at(5) << 40) |
        (S.at(6) << 48) |
        (S.at(7) << 56);

    printf("S[0] = %016llX,  S[0] << 0   = %016llX\n",S[0],S[0] );
    printf("S[1] = %016llX,  S[1] << 8   = %016llX\n",S[1],S[1] << 8);
    printf("S[2] = %016llX,  S[2] << 16  = %016llX\n",S[2],S[2] << 16);
    printf("S[3] = %016llX,  S[3] << 24  = %016llX\n",S[3],S[3] << 24);
    printf("S[4] = %016llX,  S[4] << 32  = %016llX\n",S[4],S[4] << 32);
    printf("S[5] = %016llX,  S[5] << 40  = %016llX\n",S[5],S[5] << 40);
    printf("S[6] = %016llX,  S[6] << 48  = %016llX\n",S[6],S[6] << 48);
    printf("S[7] = %016llX,  S[7] << 56  = %016llX\n",S[7],S[7] << 56);
    printf("%llX", byteS);

}
```

Вывод:

```
S[0] = 00000000000000B1,  S[0] << 0   = 00000000000000B1
S[1] = 0000000000000094,  S[1] << 8   = 0000000000009400
S[2] = 00000000000000BA,  S[2] << 16  = 0000000000BA0000
S[3] = 00000000000000C8,  S[3] << 24  = 00000000C8000000
S[4] = 000000000000000A,  S[4] << 32  = 0000000A00000000
S[5] = 0000000000000008,  S[5] << 40  = 0000080000000000
S[6] = 00000000000000F5,  S[6] << 48  = 00F5000000000000
S[7] = 000000000000003B,  S[7] << 56  = 3B00000000000000

3BF5080AC8BA94B1
```

С чем именно вы несогласны? что, по-вашему, работает не так?

Comment: Ожидалось B194BAC80A08F53B

Comment: Почему? почему в старшем разряде должно быть B1, если вы его не сдвигаете? оно и остается в младшем разряде... Или вы считаете, что `S = { 177,148,186,200,10,8,245,59 };` означает, что `S[0] == 59`? Массив записывается слева направо, байты - справа налево... Может, это различие наложило отпечаток на восприятие?

Comment: Пробовала записывать и наоборот, но ничего не получилось.
Дело в том, что это строки из стандарта. Но не смотря на мои изменения в коде нужный результат получить не могу.

Comment: Напишите `S= { 59, 245, 8, 10, 200, 186, 148, 177 };` :)